# Laravel Datatables getting net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error when adding extra column

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I'm using DataTable 1.10.21 with Laravel 7. I'm trying to populate all of the users data, except my user table has an additional column named group_id, which define the user group (ie. admin, manager, user etc)

Right now my user model has this relationship:

```
public function group() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }
```

When I call

```
App\User::select(*)->with('group')->get();
```

I'll get something like this which is good:

```
App\User {#105150
         id: 1,
         group_id: 1,
         name: "Admin",
         email: "admin@admin.com",
         email_verified_at: "2020-01-01 01:01:01",
         ...
         deleted_at: null,
         group: App\Group {#105096
           id: 1,
           name: "admin",
         },
       }
       ...
```

In my UserController I have this function:

```
public function datatable() {
        $data = User::select("*")->with('group');
        $dt = Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
        \Log::debug($dt); //this works!!
        return $dt;
    }
```

I can use tinker to get $data and $dt without any problem.

My view contains the following javascript:

```
$(function() {
               $('#table').DataTable({
               processing: true,
               serverSide: true,
               ajax: '{{ url('user/datatable') }}',
               columns: [
                        { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                        { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                        { data: 'group_id', name: 'group_id' }, /* this won't work */
                        { data: 'group.name', name: 'group.name' }, /* this won't work either */
                        { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
                        { data: 'email', name: 'email' }
                     ]
            });
         });
```

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>ID</th>
                     <th>Name</th>
                     <th>Group ID</th>
                     <th>Group Name</th>
                     <th>Creation Date</th>
                     <th>Email</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
            </table>
```

Neither of the group_id or group.name col will work. (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error even $dt has response) but if I remove both columns then it works fine.

Please advise.

**Edit: May 29 2020**

I digged a little deeper and here's what I have found:

If I use my local test domain (ie. myproject.test)

- If I remove some other columns (ie. created at, email) it worked
- If I include all columns (ie. id, name, group_id, group.name, created_at, email) I got the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error

If I use 127.0.0.1:8000

- it worked even if I include all columns!!!!

Can someone please explain to me why??

Comment: How about `$data = User::select("*")->with('group')->get()` ... adding **->get()**

Comment: @Digvijay tried that not working.

Comment: Can you please share your **id="table"**. After your edit, it seems some <th> are missing.

Comment: @Digvijay updated in first post. But again it has nothing to do with group or group ID. Please see my updated post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yajra\Datatables is one of those areas I personally prefer to use raw sql.

With your above requirements I'd see it like so

```
$data = DB::select("
Select
  a.id as 'users.id',
  a.name as 'users.name',
  b.id as 'group.id',
  b.name as 'group.name',
  a.created_at as 'users.created_at',
  a.email as 'users.email'
FROM
  users as a
LEFT JOIN 
  groups as b
ON
  a.group_id = b.id");

$data = Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
return $data;
```

Then in your columns section of your datatable initialization code just update the data with "users.id", "users.name", etc (same with the name fields).

Yajra is great, but I ran into issues with it and eloquent myself.  Hence why I just went back to raw sql, havent had a problem since.

**Edit - with new data:
Then I'd suggest you post your .env file that has been loaded to the server in question. Are you doing all of this locally or do you have a seperate server you are having problems on?**

Comment: It has nothing to do with $data. I logged $dt and $data both got output. It has something to do with the test domain. Please see my May 29 edit thanks

Comment: Then I'd suggest you post your .env file that has been loaded to the server in question.  Are you doing all of this locally or do you have a seperate server you are having problems on?

Comment: Thanks! Once I set APP_URL to myproject.test in .env it worked! Please edit your post and I'll accept your answer!

Comment: Done, updated to the bottom while leaving original incase it helps anybody else out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Yajra\DataTables`, then I can see that you don't specify a few columns well. Let's get from the beginning.

First, change in your controller to be like this:

```php
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;

    public function datatable() {
        $data = User::with(['group'])->select("users.*"); // Also select can throw ambiguous column error

        return Datatables::of($data)
           ->addColumn('group_id', function ($user) {
                return !empty($user->group) ? $user->group->id : '';
           })->addColumn('group_name', function ($user) {
                return !empty($user->group) ? $user->group->name : '';
           })->toJson(true); // Please note this line also
    }
```

Then in your JS:

```js
$(function() {
               $('#table').DataTable({
               processing: true,
               serverSide: true,
               ajax: '{{ url('user/datatable') }}',
               columns: [
                        { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                        { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                        { data: 'group_id', name: 'group.id' }, // Data is specified data in controller and name is relationship data
                        { data: 'group_name', name: 'group.name' },
                        { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
                        { data: 'email', name: 'email' }
                     ]
            });
         });
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but user will always have a group id and group name. Please see my May 29 edit

Comment: @Josh Yes, but you need to map it properly. Please try this approach, and future you can remove checking `!empty($user->group) ? $user->group->name : ''"` to `$user->group->name`